# Upload new version of live Application on TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

I want to upload a new updated version of live application on TestFlight for internal tester only. Is there any effect on the live version of the application?

Comment: No the live version will not be effected.

Comment: No it will never affect, because you must have to upload a new version, which is greater then last live version. And both are treated as different.

Comment: it does not overlap on live version?@RahulPatel @iPeter

Comment: Never. If your new version is successfully reviewed by apple team, Then you can live it. Manually or it will be automatically.

Comment: Okey @RahulPatel. Thx for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

No! it won't effect the live version of the application that is already on app store. The internal users will get a to download the version of the application from testFlight without interfering with the current version of the application.